# Proving $ac+ab+bc+1<a+b+c+abc$ when $a,b,c>1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a,b,c$ are integers, how to prove that $ac+ab+bc+1<a+b+c+abc$ when $a,b,c>1$?

I proved that $a+b<ab+1$, and attempted to use it in the solution by factoring the left side of the inequality into 
$$a(b+c)+bc+1<abc+a+bc+1$$ but after subtracting $abc$ and $a$ from both sides, I get $bc+1<b+c$, meaning I overshot with the first substitution. 

I attempted another factorization and attempted to prove 
$$ab(1-c)+ac+bc+1<a+b+c$$
Which got me to 
$$a+ac+1<a+b+c$$
Meaning I overshot once more with $ab>b$. Are there some techniques I could try out to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$abc + a + b + c - ab - ac - bc - 1 = (a - 1)(b - 1)(c - 1).$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)>0$$